# Web API Authentication (without asp.net identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to authenticate a Web API without using asp.net identity?

I have a MVC and a Web API project within the same solution, on the MVC project I have a very small Admin area protected with a login and password (just for one user). On this area I get the data on clinet side using API calls.

This is my Login function:

```
public ActionResult SubmitLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UserName == "xxxxx" && Password == "yyyyy")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", @"Admin/Users");
            }
        }
        var errors = (from value in ModelState.Values
                      from error in value.Errors
                      select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();

        if (errors.Count == 0)
        {
            errors.Add("UserName or Password are incorrect");
        }

        ViewBag.Message = errors;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

The Login form work fine, my issue is with the API calls, my API controller is `[Authorize]` but when I make a request:

```
self.getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.get("../MySite.API/Users/GetUsers/", callback);
}
```

I get a 401 error.

I understand I have to somehow send the `AuthCookie` but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `AuthorizationFilter` or `ActionFilter` to check the user's authentication and authorization before the action is executed.

This is just a sample how it can be done with `ActionFilter`. You can design your own as required:

```
public class CanEditReport : ActionFilterAttribute  
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var reportID = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.ActionParameters["id"]);
        var report = ReportsManager.GetByID(reportID);
        int userID = 0;
        bool hasID = int.TryParse(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUserID"].ToString(), out userID);
        if (!hasID)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["FlashMessage"] = "Please select a valid User to access their reports.";
            //Change the Result to point back to Home/Index
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
        }
        else //We have selected a valid user
        {
            if(report.UserID != userID)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.TempData["FlashMessage"] = "You cannot view Reports you have not created.";
                //Change the Result to point back to Home/Index
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```